# Show the length of display ="none"; using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that does style.display = "none" when a something is clicked.

I would like to know how I could find out the length of the elements that are displayed none.

```js
function closeEvent() {
 var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

 for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function () {
   var div = this.parentElement;
   div.style.display = "none";

   renderGraph();
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h1>My Daily Tasks</h1>
  <p>Add a time and task then press enter. When finished task click on task bar</p>

  <p>To delete task click on <span id="x-text">x</span> in the corner of task bar</p>
  <input type="time" id="myInput1" value="06:00">
  <input name="text" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="My task...">

  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn" id="myBtn"></span>
 </div>
 <ul id="columns">

 </ul>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to select only the elements with the **style** attribute "display:none" and get the total found.

```
var total = document.querySelectorAll('[style="display: none;"]').length
```

Take a look at the full documentation of querySelector and querySelectorAll. They are both quite powerful selectors which you can use just like a css selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: since this is the parent `div` that inline styled with `display: none;` i think you should edit this to: `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[style="display: none;"]').length);`

Comment: That's assuming there is only that one style being set inline on the element and that it will be stringified exactly like this by the browser. That's quite big assumptions.

Comment: @A.Meshu that worked. Interestingly it gave me the length followed by undefined!

Comment: @HesamAlavi i guess that's because there are situations that you don't have any element with this style attribute. You can check that with simple condition before executing the call of length.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will face is that your code may very well not be the only one to hide elements this way.
A lot of libraries also use this inline style to hide elements, for instance, that's what `jQuery.hide()` does.

So you may very well catch false positives, if the only distinction point is that style.

Depending on your exact uses, you could simply maintain an Array of these elements, if you need to keep track of them and reuse quite often:

```js
const myhidden_elements = [];
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if( e.target.matches(".hideable") ) {
    e.target.style.display = "none";
    myhidden_elements.push(e.target);
    const hidden_count = myhidden_elements.length;
    console.log( hidden_count );
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="hideable">hide me 1</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 2</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 3</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 4</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 5</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 6</div>
```

But it might even be better to add your own `class` to these hidden elements. It might be easier to maintain and to then access exactly these elements you are interested in.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if( e.target.matches(".hideable") ) {
    e.target.classList.add('my-hidden-class');
    
    const hidden_count = document.querySelectorAll('.my-hidden-class').length;
    console.log( hidden_count );
  }
});
```

```css
.my-hidden-class {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hideable">hide me 1</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 2</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 3</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 4</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 5</div>
<div class="hideable">hide me 6</div>
```